# Domain logic leakage to other layers?

Tags: model, domain-driven-design

I am having a little confusion around what should and should not be in a domain layer.

Let's say my domain expert describes a `Product` entity which consist of `title`, `price` and `description` properties and some behaviours. However taking the fact that domain expert is ultimately trying to describe a end-user look (presentation layer?) of the product a couple of questions arise:

1. Assuming that `title` and `description` are not used in the domain layer at all (they just serve as UI-presentation properties), should I put them in my domain layer, or should they exist only in a presentation layer? How should I distinguish what properties of entities my domain expert is providing truly belong to domain layer?
2. If they should only exist in presentation layer, what is the best way to deal with that? DTO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume this is for a shopping application (or similar).  Here, in this context --- the shopping context ---, a `Product` may have `description`, `price`, and `title`, and they can therefore be properties of the `Product`.

In another context (logistics, ordering, etc), a `Product` (which then is a different class) probably only has an SKU and related properties (weight, ...), but not `title` or `description`.

Comment: I would like to know what you think about cases where certain properties are relevant only for presentation purposes in this case title and description, do you include them into your domain layer or not

Comment: Yeah, that was basically my question, I am aware of having different `Product` classes across different BCs.

Comment: Yes, of course.  If it's relevant for your presentation, it's relevant for your application, hence it is part of the domain of this respective application -- even if it's "only" an "UI domain model".